# math notation of iterated function

Tags: notation, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to determine the proper notation for the following loop I have written in computer code:

> > Set x = 2   set y = 3
> >
> > For z=1 to z=5 (increasing the value of z by 1 each iteration):
> >
> > set x = x * y
> >       set y = y + z
> >
> > Solve for X

This should yield a result of x = 16848 --is there a nice way to write this loop in mathematical notation? I've thought of using summations and the capital Pi symbol, but neither seem to quite do the trick...

Comment: $x_{n+1}=x_ny_n=x_n(y_{n-1}+n-1),\ x_0=2,\ y_0=3$, which is a 1-step inhomogeneous dynamical system with variable coefficient. You simply want $x_5$, which should now be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical notation handles this kind of thing by giving a separate name to  the value of $x$ and $y$ at each state of the computation. The names  $x_0$ and $y_0$ refer to the initial states of $x$ and $y$, and then for each iteration, we compute the new values $x_{n+1}$ and $y_{n+1}$ in terms of the current values $x_n$ and $y_n$, something like this:

$$\begin{align}
x_0 & = 2 & y_0 & = 3 \\
x_{n+1} & = x_n y_n & y_{n+1} & = y_n + n & \text{for $n\in[1,\ldots,5]$}
\end{align}$$

And then the question becomes, what is the value of $x_5$?

This does have the benefit that it makes completely clear exactly what is being computed at each step. If we were to exchange the order of the $x\leftarrow xy$ and $y\leftarrow y+n$ steps, so that $y$ was updated before $x$, this would be reflected in the notation above as $x_{n+1}=x_ny_{\color{red}{n+1}}$ instead of $x_{n+1}=x_ny_n$.